# When does popup.js gets initiated?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "YouTellMe",
"description":"FIND AND COMPARE OVER 10.000.000 PRODUCTS AND GET THE BEST PRICES FROM ALL MAJOR INDIAN WEBSHOPS. GET DISCOUNTS TO HAVE THE CHEAPEST PRICE!",
"version":"0.0",

"browser_action":
{
    "default_icon":"logoytm.png",
    "default_popup": "offers.html",
    "badge" : "YTM"
},

"background" : 
{
    "scripts" : ["find_offers.js"],
    "persistent" : false
},

"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

"permissions":
[
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "webNavigation",
    "notifications",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "http://localhost/*",
]}
```

find_offers.js

```js
if( ! window.jQuery )
{
 console.log("importing jquery...")
 script = document.createElement('script');
 script.source = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js';
 document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script)
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(tab_activated);
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(load_iframe); 

var tablink;

function tab_activated()
{
 chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
       function(tabs)
       {
   tablink = tabs[0].url;
       });
}

function load_iframe()
{
 console.log("in load iframe");
 ytm_product_url = "http://localhost/bookmarklet/product/";
    console.log("current URL " + tablink);
    if(tablink != undefined)
    {
     var uri = ytm_product_url+"?retailer_url="+tablink;
    }
    else 
 {
     var uri = ytm_product_url+"?retailer_url="+document.location.href;
 }
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({url:uri});
}
```

offers.html

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/x-scss" href="bookmark_offers.css" />
<script src='jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='load_offers.js'> </script>
<body>
<div id="YTM_offers"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

load_offers.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener
(
 function (request)
    {
  alert("message received");
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url : request.url,
            }
        )
        .done
        (
            function(data)
            {
             notifyUser();
                console.log( $("#YTM_offers")[0] );
//                document.getElementById('YTM_offers').innerHTML += data;
                $("#YTM_offers").html(data);
                console.log($("#YTM_offers"));
            }
        )
    }
)


function notifyUser()
{
 console.log("notification...")
 if (! Notification)
 {
  alert('Notifications are supported in modern versions of Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Firefox.'); 
     return;
 }
 
 if(Notification.permission !== "granted")
  Notification.requestPermission();
 
 var notification = new Notification("YouTellMe", 
   {   icon : 'logoytm.png',
    body : "We've got more offers for you." +
      "\nClick on extension Icon for more details."
   });
}
```

Now the problem statement.
I send current page's url from `find_offers.js` to `load_offers.js` and then `load_offers.js` pulls the related offers from server, that is being populated in div called `YTM_offers`.

`load_offers.js` is listening for message(url) from find_offers.js but here sending part works perfectly, but receiving part does not work until I inspect popup.html and reload current page.

What I am doing wrong?
Help appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong in assuming that the popup listens for messages while it's closed.

In fact, the HTML document that contains `load_offers.js` is completely unloaded when the popup is closed, and is loaded again from scratch every time.

Therefore, sending a message to a popup is generally a bad idea, unless the popup asked first.

You need to modify your logic; either only query information when the popup opens, from within it, or store the information so that the popup can request it when opened. The latter can be difficult since you declared your background as `persistent: false` (`chrome.storage` is an option, however).

From looking at your current logic, it seems unlikely that the current page changes while the popup is open; therefore, you should just query information about the current tab when you open the popup, and you don't really need the background script in its current form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes you are write, I realize that after reading the question header. so now I want to pull data from server in background js, and notify user that data is ready, click on icon for data, as popup can't be opened pragmatically.

Comment: So. Do it! Pull the data, if there's interesting information for the user - use `browserAction.setBadgeText` or change the icon to indicate that you have information to show, and store that information in `chrome.storage`. In the popup, pull the data from `chrome.storage` when it opens.

Comment: Thanks for the idea (chrome.storage)